# intelij линии иерархии кода

Tags: intellij-idea

Всем привет, как включить сетку, которая показывает вложенность кода? 
Проводит вертикальную линию от начала и до конца блока.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажимаете на список с номерами строк правой кнопкой мыши и выбираете пункт "Show Indent Guides".